# ringtone can not be stopped

Tags: java, android, limit, ringtone

I'm developing a speedometer app and now working on some kind of speed limit function. The idea is to make noise when speed gets bigger than the target value. The code I use:

```
Ringtone ringtone;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.updateSpeed(null);
}


private void updateSpeed(Location location){
    ...
    float speed = location.getSpeed();
    int i = (int) speed;
    this.doLimit(i);
}

private void doLimit(int i) {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
                if (i >= 50) { 
                    this.lets_dance();
                } else {
                    if (ringtone.isPlaying()) {
                        ringtone.stop();
                    }
                }
}

private void lets_dance() {
           ringtone.play();
           Timer timer = new Timer();
           timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
                public void run(){
                      if(!ringtone.isPlaying()){
                          ringtone.play();
                      }
                }
            }, 1000, 1000);
}
```

The problem is that the ringtone is playing the first time the speed exceeds 50 and doesn't stop.

Before I tried a lot of methods of using Mediaplayer with and without setLooping and situation was even worse (it caused app to lag like I'm using it on the calculator).

Comment: There are multiple errors in the code fragments which tells me we're not seeing real code. `scheduleAtFisedRate`?  `ringtone.play;` Why not post the actual code?

Comment: Had to write code from my mind, now everything should be correct

Answer (score 0):

It could be because each time doLimit() is called, a new instance of ringtone is created. Try with the following lines in the onCreate() function:

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
```

Comment: I tried, the problem is still there. Sometimes, when speed value gets lower than target one, app lags and shuts down, but ringtone stops. Sometimes ringtone just doesn’t stop at all